# Getting an errorcode=H10 in my Python-Heroku website while using os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")

Tags: python, sql, flask, heroku

While using mysql as my database system i recieved no error but after applying Heroku-postgreSQL addon i got an error like this:

> "sqlite:///portfolioswebsite.db"at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gokay-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=4e41ecde-2141-4ae4-a3f5-1de1896a10ab dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I checked all the lines in my code whenever I change app.config below to this

> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ="sqlite:///portfolioswebsite.db">

to this:

> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =
> os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///portfolioswebsite.db")

I receive this error.

Here is also my Procfile

> web: gunicorn main:app

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to define the environment variable should be:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
```

Then on Heroku you should define the value of `DATABASE_URL` with the whole URL to your DB, in this case if you are using PostgreSQL as the add-on, when you set up the add, it should automatically set that config var and its value.

Comment: I guess there is no big difference in my definition. I used the second parameter as a default just for local running. If there is a "DATABASE_URL" then there is no need for "sqlite:///portfolioswebsite.db". Yes add-on automatically did but doesn't work I don't know why maybe because of conversion sqllite to postgreSQL

Comment: Since you are using PostgreSQL on Heroku, best approach will be to use postgres as the DB Engine.